# ¿Como mejorar la calidad imagen en jspdf

Tags: javascript, canvas, jspdf

Estoy imprimiendo un código de barras con [jsBarcode](https://lindell.me/JsBarcode/), lo imprimo un archivo pdf, pero al momento de agregarlo al pdf se de menos calidad que si fuera en la web, de momento solo sucede con el código de barras, con otras imágenes no parece haber problemas.

Para insertarlo en un pdf utilizo [`canvas`](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas), el código que utilizo para crear el **código de barras** y agregarlo al **pdf**

```
const canvas = createCanvas();
JsBarcode(canvas, ref); // lenar
const barcode =  canvas.toDataURL();
const width = canvas.width * 0.264583;
const height = canvas.height * 0.264583;
doc.addImage(barcode, 'PNG', initial, 185, width, height, 'barcode', 'NONE');
```

utilizo esta parte para cambiar el tamaño que ocupara en el **PDF** ya que su tamaño normal esta en pixeles al parecer y el pdf utiliza mm. Por lo que ocupa mucho espacio si lo dejo con pixeles.

```
const width = canvas.width * 0.264583;
const height = canvas.height * 0.264583;
```

uno de los parametros de `addImage` es la `compression` en el cual esta en `NONE`, pero tambien probé todas las opciones posibles: `'NONE'`, `'FAST'`, `'MEDIUM'` and `'SLOW'`

pero el resultado sigue siendo el mismo.
Aquí dejo imagenes de como se muestra en el **navegador** y como se muestra en el **PDF**.

1. Navegador
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
2. PDF
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intentando establecer el tamaño de `JsBarcode`

```
JsBarcode(canvas, 'hello', {width:0.4, height: 4, fontSize:5});
```

Resultado obtenido

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Parece que estás escalando la imagen y eso puede ser lo que genera diferencias en la calidad, ¿y si intentas crear el canvas desde un principio con el tamaño objetivo y evitas escalar el `width` y el `height`?

Comment: @DanielRodríguezMeza ya trate de escalar el `canvas`, pero no respecta las medidas que yo coloco, toma las medidas de `jsBarcode` y al cambiar el `width` y `height`  lo que ocasiona que tenga mucho peor calidad que antes.

Comment: @Richard debes ampliar el tamaño de tu canvas, si no respeta las medidas entonces amplia las medidas de `jsBarcode` o establecelas a lo que desees, ya que aparentemente el canvas que creas se encuentra ligado a `jsBarcode` por ende la solucion no es intentar expandir ni  mucho menos escalar el canvas si no configurar `jsBarcode` para generar el output con medidas distintas.

Comment: @Riven edite mi pregunta para mostrar el resultado al modificar directamente el tamaño en `JsBarcode`

Answer (score 1):

Esto puede mejorar un poco la calidad de la imagen que te avienta `canvas.toDataURL`, pero no es mucha la diferencia... realmente por lo que te debes preocupar es que el output de tu `jsBarcode` te devuelva una imagen un poco mas grande, ya que es este el que te genera al final los pixeles del codigo de barras.

Muy bien, si nos fijamos un momento en esta pagina de aqui:

[HTMLCanvasElement toDataURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL)

Podemos observar que la calidad por defecto que se genera como output al usar un `toDataURL` es del 92%, que igual es bastante decente, sin embargo podemos modificarla al 100%, pasandole ciertos parametros al metodo:

```
const barcode =  canvas.toDataURL('image/png', 1.0);
```

Sin embargo ten cuidado con ese metodo, puesto que puede que en algunos navegadores un tipo que sea diferente de `image/webp` **no esta soportado**.

En caso de no ser soportado la bajada de calidad puede deberse entonces a que el output final esta intentando usar una codificacion diferente, como lo puede ser `.webp` pero esta siendo guardada como una imagen `jpeg` o `png`, el formato `webp`, no resulta ser un formato de muy alta calidad...

Comment: En algunos casos la imagen puede verse corrompida tambien si el tipo difiere, a mi por ejemplo ya me paso, pero no recuerdo si fue en `firefox` de linux o en `edge chromium` en windows.

Comment: he intentado cambiar el tamaño de `jsBarcode`, si realiza el cambio establecido en px, pero el pdf dibuja con medidas `mm`, para que quepa en el pdf, tengo que establecer `width:0.4, height: 4` lo cual da muy mala calidad.